# JPA Query for fomat Date

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

In Data base , createdDt is storing formated like:

> 15-01-20 10:43:20.394000000 AM

I am passing "created" as `dd-mm-yyyy`

I want to take the matching date from the table(without comparing time)

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM ABC p WHERE ( COALESCE(:created) is null or p.createdDt = :created) order by p.createdDt desc")
    List<ABC> filterABC(@Param("created") Date created);
```

How to parse the date within query ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use native query using specific DBMS stuff to extract date part.

`@Query(value = "SELECT * from ABC where DATE_FORMAT(createdDt, '%d-%m-%Y') = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<ABC> filterABC(Date created);`

*DATE_FORMAT* is MySQL specific function. Use the appropriate date function in accordance with your DBMS